# Non ActiveX scrollbar change event?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a modern Excel scroll bar (not the old ActiveX type i.e. Developer > Insert > Form Control > Scrollbar) and would like to detect when it's value is changed. I can't find anything about a change event for this type of object. You can assign a macro on click, but I'd like my code to run on scroll.

I've tried linking it to a cell on a hidden sheet and using the worksheet change event for the hidden sheet but the event doesn't fire. I've also tried the Workbook_SheetChange event without sucess.

How can I emulate an On_Scroll event for a non ActiveX scrollbar? Thanks.

Comment: When you say 'modern' Excel scroll bar - which particular one are you referring to?

Comment: A form control (Developer > Insert > Form Control > Scrollbar), I'll update the post, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you you follow the menu path you described (Developer > Insert > Form Control > Scrollbar) and you can 'draw' the scrollbar onto the spreadsheet. Then right-click the scrollbar and select 'Assign Macro':

[image]

Note the scroll bar has a name in the top left - 'Scroll Bar 1'. A macro name will be suggested - you can leave that and then click 'New':

[image]

Now you can write VBA code. It really isn't clear what the best practice is to then get a reference to that particular scroll bar object. The way I've done it below is to:

- Given that the scroll bar is a `Shape` as well as a form control we can get its name from `Application.Caller`
- Iterate the `ScrollBars` member of the `Worksheet` class until we get a matching object
- Get the `Value` property from the object to get the current position of the thumb in the scroll bar

Note that this `ScrollBars` member of the `Worksheet` class is 'hidden' and you can see it if you go to the VBE Object Browser, right click in the 'Search Results' and select 'Show Hidden Members' and then search for `ScrollBars`. There's very little available when you Google for this because obviously the higher-ranked searches are all about the regular scroll bars in Excel, or the ones you would use in a `UserForm` or something. Anyway, the code that works for me is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScrollBar1_Change()

    Dim strCaller As String
    Dim objScrollBar As Object
    Dim dblScrollValue As Double

    ' the scroll bar has a shape - so you can get the shape name
    strCaller = Application.Caller

    ' iterate hidden scrollbars member of worksheet class to get the object
    For Each objScrollBar In Sheet1.ScrollBars
        If objScrollBar.Name = strCaller Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' get the scroll bar value
    dblScrollValue = objScrollBar.Value

    ' do something with the value
    MsgBox dblScrollValue

End Sub
```

Comment: Weird, I had tried that approach before posting but it wouldn't fire. Even assigning a different macro to the bar and clicking on it wouldn't run any code. So, suspicious that something was wrong I deleted the bar, added a new one and it works. Odd, anyway thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: You can reference the scroll bar with a variable too!  `Dim myScrollBar as ScrollBar: Set myScrollBar = Sheet1.ScrollBars("Scroll Bar 1")`

Answer (score 0):

I handled it this way. By overtly plugging the value into the Linked Cell (with the value it already has), it triggers the Change event.

```
Private Sub ScrollBar11_Change()
    Range(ScrollBar11.LinkedCell) = ScrollBar11.Value
End Sub
```